# li-ion pack charging with buck boost xl6009

Tags: lithium-ion, charging

I'd like some feedback on implementing a CC CV 3s li-ion (laptop) battery pack charger using a 12V supply and a XL6009 switched regulator.

I want to use a current sensing module to sends it's analog output to the feedback pin on the xl6009 thus implementing a Constant Current.

Usually the feedback pin is connected to a node on a voltage divider which adjusts output to make sure the voltage at the node stays at 1.25V but I would break this connection with a zener diode. When voltage at the output gets to around 12.6V the diode allows a reverse current overriding the current sensor and producing voltage regulation.

Here's the generic XL6009 schematic:
[image]

And then here's the hacked version:

[image]

Comment: I think there might be a problem with the small current sensitivity. Normally about 5mA will flow through R1 (on the bottom). When zero current is flowing about 4mA will still come through the current sensor since it never falls below 2.5v. Thus it will only take 1mA from the zener diode to make the current through the load stop which might be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

This is not how I would do this, have a look at [this forum](http://www.eevblog.com/forum/reviews/b3603-dcdc-buck-converter-mini-review-and-how-the-set-key-could-be-fatal/75/), there someone posted a schematic of an adjustable DCDC downconverter with current limiting. Note how it uses an opamp to amplify the voltage across a current shunt resistor, the output of the opamp then influences the feedback input of the Switching regulator (in this case the LM2596) via a diode.

When the current becomes too large, the opamp output voltage increases, via the diode the FB input of the LM2596 is pulled up, the LM2596 then lowers the output voltage. This scheme will also work with an XL6009.

Comment: so whats the problem the above implementation?

Comment: I don't think it's an "elegant" circuit, the current feedback always interferes with the voltage feedback even when the current is small. I doubt if there is enough gain from output current to feedback voltage. But if you think it is better than my proposal, please prove I'm wrong :-)